# Software to approximate area of curve

Tags: area, math-software, greens-theorem

Does any know of a math program where I can measure the area of a closed parametric curve ?

I know that I can measure the area between 2 curves with the TI-Nspire, but not for one curve in parametric form.

I'm looking to verify my answer for the following curve (area of left and right side separately).

[image]

If you're curious the parametric equation of the curve is :

$$x(t) = e^{\sin(\pi t)}$$
$$y(t) = e^{\sin(2\pi t)}$$
$$ 0 \leq t \leq 2 $$

Using Greens Theorem, I get $0.8445 \text{ units}^2$ for the left side and $2.7726 \text{ units}^2$ for the right side.

I'm just looking for a software where I can check my answers my self.

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: ∫y dx boundaries in terms of t

Comment: and dx = (dx/dt) dt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equation of the boundary is
$$0\leq t \leq 2,\ \begin{cases}
x(t) = e^{\sin(\pi t)}\\
y(t) = e^{\sin(2\pi t)}
\end{cases}$$
First, change it to the non-parametric form. Let $p=\ln x$ and $q=\ln y$. Thus
$$q^2=4p^2(1-p^2)\Rightarrow q=\pm 2p\sqrt{1-p^2}$$
or
$$y=e^{\pm 2\ln x \ \sqrt{1-(\ln x)^2}}$$

We are interested in the region $R=R_1\cap R_2$ between the two curves. We consider it in two cases:

- $\frac{1}{e}<x \le 1 \Rightarrow R_1=\{(x,y):e^{2\ln x \ \sqrt{1-(\ln x)^2}} \le y\le e^{- 2\ln x \ \sqrt{1-(\ln x)^2}}\}$
- $1<x \le e \Rightarrow R_2=\{(x,y):e^{-2\ln x \ \sqrt{1-(\ln x)^2}} \le y\le e^{ 2\ln x \ \sqrt{1-(\ln x)^2}}\}$

Now we calculate the probability that a random point in a box $B$ defined as

$$B=\{(x,y): 0\le x\le 3, 0\le y\le3\}$$

is inside the regions $R_1$ and $R_2$, respectively.

To do that, we randomly select $N$ points $(x,y)$ in the given box and count those that are inside the desired region. If $M_i$ points are inside the desired region $R_i$, then the desired probability is $M_i/N$ (for $i=1,2$). But this probability is related to the area of the box and the area of the desired region as

$$\frac{\mathsf{Area}(R_i)}{\mathsf{Area}(B)}\approx\frac{M_i}{N}$$
Thus

$$\boxed{\mathsf{Area}(R_i)\approx\frac{9M_i}{N}}$$

Based on the above explanation, one can use the following Matlab code:

```
t = 0:.01:2; % first draw the boundary
x = exp(sin(pi*t));
y = exp(sin(2*pi*t));
plot(x,y)
hold on

N = 50000;
M1 = 0; %initialize the counters
M2 = 0;
for n = 1:N
    x = 3*rand; % uniformly random x between 0 and 3
    y = 3*rand; % uniformly random y between 0 and 3
    if x>=exp(-1) && x <= 1
        if y<=exp(-2*log(x).*sqrt(1-log(x).^2)) && ...
              y>=exp(2*log(x).*sqrt(1-log(x).^2))
          M1 = M1+1; % the point is in R1
          plot(x,y,'r')
        end
    elseif x>=1 && x <= exp(1)
        if y<=exp(2*log(x).*sqrt(1-log(x).^2)) && ...
              y>=exp(-2*log(x).*sqrt(1-log(x).^2))
          M2 = M2+1; % the point is in R2
          plot(x,y,'g')
        end        
    end
end
A1=9*M1/N
A2=9*M2/N
```

which gives `A1 = 0.8474` and `A2 = 2.7940`.

[image]

The accuracy can be improved by increasing $N$.

Comment: Wow thats amazing ! I didn't even know Matlab could do that. Could this work with any other closed curves if I change the equations and points of intersection ?

Comment: Yes, this is called a [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).

Answer (score 1):

If you can parametrise the region, not just the boundary, then Mathematica can do it. Here it is for the unit disk:

```
Area[ParametricRegion[{Cos[t] a, Sin[t] a}, {{t, -Pi, Pi}, {a, 0, 1}}]]
```

Output is `Pi`. Hopefully the syntax is clear from context: the parametrisation of the disk is as $(\cos(t) a, \sin(t) a)$ for $-\pi \leq t < \pi$ and $0 \leq a \leq 1$.

You can use http://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/objects/wpl/GetStarted.nb (replacing the example code `2+2` with whatever you want) to run Mathematica expressions.

Comment: Thank you ! That will be very useful to me, just Im not sure I know how to parametrise the region as opposed to the boundary