# Probability of a point lying inside a square which is inscribed in a circle

Tags: probability, geometry, circles

[image: square_inscribed_in_circle]

***CD*** and ***EF*** are two diameters of the circle shown in image and ***CEDF*** is a square inscribed in the circle. If a point inside the circle is randomly chosen what is the probability that the point will lie inside the square?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You'll get a much warmer response from the community if you show what you've tried.

Comment: Assuming that *randomly* means *according to a uniform distribution* the answer is simply given by the ratio between the area of the square and the area of the circle, i.e. $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: I tried to find the probability by dividing the area of the square by the area of the circle which results a probability of 2/pi . Am I correct? Or the process is not like how I've tried.

Comment: @AbdullahShahriar That's how you do it!

Comment: It depends on how rigorous (pedantic) you want to define "random" is.  I think it is safe to assume the do mean probability is proportional to area so the probability is $\frac {A(square)}{A(circle)}$.  The only real trick is determining the area of a square by its diagonal radius of the circle, but it's not hard so see that is $2r^2$ so we have $\frac 2{\pi}$.  So, yes, I'd say you have the correct answer.

Comment: I'm also interested to know if I do this experiment for a large number of time (1 million times or more) will the probability from the experiment be close to the theoretical probability? If it deviates in huge extent then what is the reason for the deviation?

Comment: The opposite (i.e. numerical calculation of the area based on the probabilities) is also used. Here is a relevant [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2369951/350875).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

A common length of the square and the circle is the radius of the circle. If the radius of the circle is $1$, what is the area of the square?

The probability will be the ratio of the two areas.

Spoiler:

> If the radius of the circle is $1$, then its area is $\pi$. If half of the diagonal of the square is $1$, then its side is $\sqrt{2}$ (think isoceles right triangle), making its area is $2$, and the probability is the ratio of the two areas, $2/\pi$.

Comment: This is how I've tried to find out the probability and the answer I found is 2/pi. I'm interested to know another thing here. If I try this experiment in real life for a million times, will the probability be close to 2/pi?

Comment: " If I try this experiment in real life for a million times, will the probability be close to 2/pi?"  In theory.  Do you have doubts?  you might want to consider if you paint dots on the x-y plain each $\frac 1{1000}$ units apart so that there are a million dot's in the square how many dots will be in the circle?  And if you pick dots at random....

Comment: I wrote a program in Python to calculate the probability for a million random pairs (which lies inside the circle) and tried to find the value of pi from the probability. But almost always I'm getting 2.14 as a result. This means the probability is not close to our theoretical value, what is causing this deviation?

Comment: @AbdullahShahriar Hard to know without looking at your code (that's probably best suited for Stack Overflow) but $2.14$ does look an awful lot like $\pi - 1$ ...